# FTP file in secure way - Openssl to encrypt and decrypt a folder/files - gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child died with signal 13

Tags: openssl, ftp, zip, sftp, tar

**Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9** (Maipo)

**OpenSSL** 1.1.0f  25 May 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020)

The end-user doesn't have a SFTP server setup and gave me a FTP server to get some artifacts. To transfer the file over internet to FTP, it's better to secure the file first and for that I used the following post: https://www.tecmint.com/encrypt-decrypt-files-tar-openssl-linux/

Basically, to create the secure `.tar.gz` / a `.tgz` file from a folder, I used the following command to password-protect and encrypt it, it worked.

```
# tar -czf - * | openssl enc -e -aes256 -out secured.tar.gz
```

and to decrypt the file, use the following (I'm not using `-C <folder>` option) like mentioned as per the post to put the contents of secured .tar.gz file into some folder):

```
# openssl enc -d -aes256 -in secured.tar.gz | tar xz
```

This worked on my machine for encrypting and decrypting (prompts for password and does it's job).

When the end-user got the same file (**md45sum** value of the files is same at my end and their end, they got the following error message.

- **PS:** They entered the *correct* password as using the same password works, on my side.

In my case, the file is with .tgz extension.

```
$ openssl enc -d -aes256 -in secure-artifact-package-1.0.0.tgz | tar xz -C artifact_1.0.0
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
 
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child died with signal 13
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error writing output file
```

Told them to try with `-C artifact_1.0.0` and got the same error mesg.

Why this error mesg is comming when the password is correct?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End-user was using an older version of OpenSSL on their side and that seems like to have caused this password related problem during decryption i.e. if a file is created using the above way using `OpenSSL version X` and if you try to decrypt it using `OpenSSL version Y`, then this issue comes.

After end-user installed the same OpenSSL version (or possibly a newer version than mine would resolve as well), the issue went away.

The issue was resolved after installing the following OpenSSL version on their Linux machine.

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0f 25 May 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS 21 Apr 2020)
```